# How to preserve custom web.config settings in GeneXus 16

Tags: configuration, web-deployment, genexus

When you build a GeneXus app, the .Net Generator produces the web.config file which gets deployed. I want to add some custom settings to the web.config file, for example URL rewrite rules, in such a way that they are not lost when the build process happens.

How or where would I do this in GeneXus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already taken a look at Build Events?

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39474,Build%20Events

You can program something that adds the URL rewrite rules to a web.config file maybe using XMLWriter and then add this program to the Post-build Events so it is executed after every GeneXus Build and the file is kept up to date.

Comment: Instead of a link, please include what your solution would be specifically.

Comment: That's probably as close to an ideal solution as I'm going to get. It's a pity there's no way to do this within GeneXus, and I have to make a separate project, and store these settings outside of my GeneXus KB, but I haven't found a better solution so I'm accepting this answer. Thanks.